# Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the following code to update rows in a database table:

```
MissioniDataSet missioniDataSet = new MissioniDataSet();
    MissioniDiarieTableAdapter missioniDiarieTableAdapter = new MissioniDiarieTableAdapter();
    missioniDiarieTableAdapter.Fill(missioniDataSet.MissioniDiarie);
    foreach (MissioniDataSet.MissioniDiarieRow i in missioniDataSet.MissioniDiarie.Rows)
    {
        i.Diaria = Decimal.Parse(((TextBox)Page.FindControl("importo" + i.DiariaID)).Text);
        i.AccontoMax = Decimal.Parse(((TextBox)Page.FindControl("acconto" + i.DiariaID)).Text);            
    }
    missioniDiarieTableAdapter.Update(missioniDataSet.MissioniDiarie);
```

But when I run it, I receive the following error:

> *Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.*

Why? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite literal and clear, the problem is with your Adapter, it is missing an UPDATE SQL statement.

Apparently you are using a generated adapter. Try re-configuring it. But be aware, the slightest deviation from the normal `SELECT x, y FROM t` pattern and the tools will fail. But you can always write the UPDATE (and you probably need DELETE, INSERT as well) statements yourself.

Comment: And if this above doesn't address the problem (and it should) you need to edit your question to explain how not.